# Automatically add new series to COMBO chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I'm trying to get a combo chart to automatically add new data series into it when the underlying named range is expanded.

My excel chart is a simple combo chart with one series as a line (max capacity) and all other series as a stacked area chart (one series per project). This would allow me to easily see where the sum of the different projects exceeds my max capacity at any point in time.

See example:

[image: Example Chart:]

My problem is tho that when I add a new range to the base table the chart does not automatically update.

All other chart types seem to expand, and I've seen multiple posts suggesting ways of fixing this for other charts (including the named range trick). However the behavior for a combo chart seems to be different.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to create `Dynamic Named Range`,, will always use the new set of data for the set procedure when included !!

Comment: I can get the dynamic range to work if I'm trying to extend the existing series, but don't seem to work when I'm adding new series.... unless I'm missing something, doing it incorrectly?